# How can I build the Kivy app for android?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I've installed all packages(pip, cython, devutils, kivyMd), bun when i ran:
python3 main.py, i have an error:

```
 --- Logging error ---
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/kivy/input/providers/__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
     import kivy.input.providers.mtdev
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/kivy/input/providers/mtdev.py", line 94, in <module>
     from kivy.lib.mtdev import Device, \
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/kivy/lib/mtdev.py", line 30, in <module>
     libmtdev = cdll.LoadLibrary('libmtdev.so.1')
   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ctypes/__init__.py", line 451, in LoadLibrary
     return self._dlltype(name)
   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ctypes/__init__.py", line 373, in __init__
     self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
 OSError: libmtdev.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/logging/__init__.py", line 1085, in emit
     msg = self.format(record)
   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/logging/__init__.py", line 929, in format
     return fmt.format(record)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/kivy/logger.py", line 291, in format
     record = copy.deepcopy(record)
   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/copy.py", line 172, in deepcopy
     y = _reconstruct(x, memo, *rv)
   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/copy.py", line 270, in _reconstruct
     state = deepcopy(state, memo)
   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/copy.py", line 146, in deepcopy
     y = copier(x, memo)
   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/copy.py", line 230, in _deepcopy_dict
     y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/copy.py", line 146, in deepcopy
     y = copier(x, memo)
   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/copy.py", line 210, in _deepcopy_tuple
     y = [deepcopy(a, memo) for a in x]
   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/copy.py", line 210, in <listcomp>
     y = [deepcopy(a, memo) for a in x]
   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/copy.py", line 161, in deepcopy
     rv = reductor(4)
 TypeError: cannot pickle 'traceback' object
 Call stack:
   File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
     from kivymd.app import MDApp
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 848, in exec_module
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/kivymd/app.py", line 50, in <module>
     from kivymd.theming import ThemeManager
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 848, in exec_module
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/kivymd/theming.py", line 219, in <module>
     from kivy.core.window import Window
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 848, in exec_module
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/kivy/core/window/__init__.py", line 2460, in <module>
     Window = core_select_lib('window', window_impl, True)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/kivy/core/__init__.py", line 59, in core_select_lib
     mod = importlib.__import__(name='{2}.{0}.{1}'.format(
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1093, in __import__
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 848, in exec_module
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 34, in <module>
     from kivy.input.provider import MotionEventProvider
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 848, in exec_module
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/kivy/input/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
     from kivy.input.postproc import kivy_postproc_modules
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 848, in exec_module
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/kivy/input/postproc/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
     from kivy.input.postproc.calibration import InputPostprocCalibration
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 848, in exec_module
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/kivy/input/postproc/calibration.py", line 51, in <module>
     from kivy.input import providers
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1042, in _handle_fromlist
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 848, in exec_module
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/kivy/input/providers/__init__.py", line 44, in <module>
     Logger.exception(err)
 Message: 'Input: MTDev is not supported by your version of linux'
 Arguments: ()
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: x11(['window_sdl2'] ignored)
Couldn't connect to X server
```

python3
ubuntu(from win store)

Problems may be in cause of this errors:
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python3-devutils (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for python3-devutils

Comment: Welcome to SO! Would you please [edit] the question and copy-paste the `main.py` file as well?

Comment: error shows problem with `libmtdev.so.1` and it may need to install `apt install libmtdev`. Check first `apt search libmtdev` to get full name for this library.